# Hestenes' Existence of Extreme Points

Tags: real-analysis

While reading Magnus R. Hestenes' "Optimization Theory: The Finite Dimensional Case", I encountered the following theorem:

> **Theorem 2.1** Let $f$ be a continuous function on a closed set $S$. Suppose that there is a number $b$ such that the set $S_b$ of all
>   points $x$ in $S$ having $f(x)\leqslant b$ is bounded and nonnull.
>   Then $f$ attains its minimum at a point $x_0$ in $S$, that is,
>   $f(x_0)=\inf f(x)$ on $S$.

For some reason, I do not like this formulation. Therefore, I rewrote it in the following way:

> **Theorem 2.1** If $f:S\subset\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is continuous, $S$ is closed, and $f$ is bounded below, then there exists an $x_0$ in
>   $S$ such that $f(x_0)=\inf f$.

Am I right in doing this? If not, then what am I missing from the original statement?

Comment: why is it important S is closed?

Comment: Take $f(x)=x^2$ on $S=(0,\infty)$. Then $\inf_Sf=0$, but there exists no $x_0\in S$ such that $f(x_0)=0$.

Comment: the way you write it is wrong. consider $f(x) = \exp(x)$ on $\mathbb R$. You let out the compact argument :)

Comment: @user251257 I see; the horizontal asymptote is breaking it. Can I still salvage it by requiring that $f (S) $ also be closed?

Comment: @Josué: Yes. If $f(S)$ is closed, then we have $\inf_S f \in f(S)$. However that's a rather strong condition and hard to test in general. It is better to demand that a sublevel set $\{ x \mid f(x) \le b \}$ is bounded.

Comment: @user251257 You are right. Thank you for your help. If you write your comments into an answer, then I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rephrased statement is wrong. Consider $f(x)=exp(x)$ on $\mathbb R$. Notice that every sublevel set is either unbound or empty.

If $f(S)$ is closed, then we have $\inf_S f \in f(S)$. Thus, the statement is valid. However that's a rather strong condition and hard to test in general. It is better to demand that a sublevel set $\{ x \mid f(x)\le b\}$ is bounded.